# Можно ли нарисовать границу CSS?

Tags: css, css3

К примеру необходимо что б граница у элемента (блок, кнопка) были в виде звезды, зайчика или другой произвольно нарисованной границы.
Можно ли чистым css что-то придумать, что б свойства border-* работали в с таким оформлением границы?

Comment: для этих целей рациональнее использовать svg, на мой взгляд.

Comment: в css если для этого свойство border-image

Answer (score 1):

Вторя словам @Sergey Archipov:

```css
img {
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/65/9c/32659c885180c2698db29df9b91175ef.png) 10% stretch round;
  -o-border-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/65/9c/32659c885180c2698db29df9b91175ef.png) 10% stretch round;
  border-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/65/9c/32659c885180c2698db29df9b91175ef.png) 10% stretch round;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/4420/120710424.a2/0_6d8e5_a305153f_L.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: отчисти да, но опять же рамка-изображение стандартизировано, я не могу с помощью этого свойства сделать блок ввиде произвольной (не прямоугольной) формы.